# Magento 2 testing module setup

Tags: magento2, setup-script, install-script, testing

How is it possible to test module setup in Magento2 ?
I have following setup class:

```
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup->startSetup();
        $quoteExtraFieldsTbl = $installer->getConnection()->newTable();

        $quoteExtraFieldsTbl->addColumn(
            'quote_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'primary' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'unsigned' => true
            ]
        );
        $quoteExtraFieldsTbl->addColumn(
            'delivery_date',
            Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false]
        );
        $quoteExtraFieldsTbl->addColumn(
            'deliver_to_neighbours',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            5,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 0]
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($quoteExtraFieldsTbl);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

How should be tested the proper creation of the table ?

Comment: you have to run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: In case you are talking about unit testing it, I may be wrong, but I don't think you need to test this since the table creation script is just a configuration. You don't add any logic to you project. You just configure some fields and use methods from other classes that should be tested on their own. But honestly, I'm curious about this too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the previous answer.
I've made the following integration test:

```
namespace ......\Test\Integration;

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList;
use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;
use Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager;

class OrderExtraFieldsTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    const MODULE_NAME = '...._OrderExtraFields';

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resource;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->objectManager = Bootstrap::getObjectManager();

        $this->resource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $this->connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
    }

    public function testModuleIsRegistered()
    {
        $registrar = new ComponentRegistrar();
        $paths = $registrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey(self::MODULE_NAME, $paths);
    }

    public function testModuleEnabled()
    {
        /* @var $moduleList ModuleList */
        $moduleList = $this->objectManager->create(ModuleList::class);
        $message = sprintf('The module %s is not enabled', self::MODULE_NAME);
        $this->assertTrue($moduleList->has(self::MODULE_NAME), $message);
    }

    public function testTablesCreated()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(
            $this->connection->isTableExists(
                $this->resource->getTableName('quote_extra_fields')
            )
        );

        $this->assertTrue(
            $this->connection->isTableExists(
                $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_extra_fields')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the great [article](http://vinaikopp.com/2016/02/05/01_the_skeleton_module_kata) to Vinai Kopp